# The avatar in the comment component of semantic-ui got distorted unpurposely

Tags: semantic-ui

I'm trying to use the comment component from semantic-ui, but the avatar of which seems like got distorted.

The minimal working demo code is here: https://gist.github.com/cnnblike/5491ac2d4ce5d2205dbafcc5f51b8127
Do you have any idea what's actually going wrong?

This code works strangely on Chrome and IE but totally okay on fiddle here: 
`jsfiddle.net/9gmzvk2p/6/embed`

the result behaves like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

just compare the iframe page and the local page one bit by one bit, and find the  at the beginning is the answer to the difference.
So the problem got solved, finally.